# missing 'ext-gd' in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Error missing 'ext-gd' in laravel 7 when run `composer u` command.

```
D:\wamp64\www\ranking-master>composer u
Loading composer repositories with package information
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.0-RC1, ..., v8.0.3] require php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 || ~7.3.0 -> your php version (8.1.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.4, ..., v8.0.7] require php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 || ~7.3.0 || ~7.4.0 -> your php version (8.1.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.8, ..., v8.0.9] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.10, ..., v8.0.12] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 || ~8.0.0 -> your php version (8.1.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.13, ..., v8.1.4] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
    - niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf[v4.0.0, ..., v4.1.0] require mpdf/mpdf ^8.0 -> satisfiable by mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.0-RC1, ..., v8.1.4].
    - Root composer.json requires niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf ^4.0 -> satisfiable by niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf[v4.0.0, v4.1.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-gd` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

D:\wamp64\www\ranking-master>php --ini`enter code here`
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

D:\wamp64\www\ranking-master>composer --ignore-platform-req=ext-gd
```

file composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8.1.12",
    "awssat/laravel-visits": "^3.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "intervention/image": "^2.6",
    "kavenegar/php": "^1.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
    "morilog/jalali": "3.\*",
    "niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf": "^4.0",
    "orangehill/iseed": "^3.0",
    "tucker-eric/eloquentfilter": "^2.4",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0"
}
```

hi. i try to run `composer u` and update packages but show me error !

The project's PHP was 7 and I manually changed it to PHP 8

please help me.

Comment: Is there anything unclear about that error  message? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a 3rd party package requires a specific extension to be enabled

```
mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.13, ..., v8.1.4] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
```

try install it first and run `composer u` again

Comment: thanks for help me. i activate `extension gd` in file php.ini and worked ;)

Comment: glad to be able to help fellow laravel artisan ^_^